# How to send an image to telegram bot and forward it with Mailgun?

Tags: python

I need users to send images to Bot and the Bot forward images to some email address with Mailgun:

My code looks like this:

```
def send_mail(update: Update,context: CallbackContext):
    file = context.bot.get_file(update.message.photo[-1].file_id)
    f = cv2.imdecode(numpy.fromstring(BytesIO(file.download_as_bytearray()).getvalue(), numpy.uint8), 1)


    mail=requests.post(
    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/domain.com/messages",
    auth=("api", "token"),
    files=[("attachment", open(f).read())],
    data={"from": "Bot" Telegram <bot@bot.us>",
          "to": "someuser@somemail.com",
          "subject": "New User via Telegram",
          "text": f"New user Created via Telegram. \n \n Email: {email_address},  \n Username:{user_name}, \n"})
    print(mail.status_code)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aras/Desktop/BitplayDepositBot/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 555, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/home/aras/Desktop/BitplayDepositBot/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/ext/conversationhandler.py", line 626, in handle_update
    new_state = handler.handle_update(update, dispatcher, check_result, context)
  File "/home/aras/Desktop/BitplayDepositBot/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 198, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "/home/aras/Desktop/BitplayDepositBot/depositbot/registration.py", line 123, in send_mail
    files=[("attachment", open(f).read())],
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ndarray
```

Comment: please show the full traceback. Otherwise it's not clear where exactly the exception happens.

Comment: Sorry, i've updated the post. Thanks